# kendo ui mobile listview for displaying checkbox

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I want to display a check box for all the list items in a kendo mobile listview,
So, I have given  in my kendo listview template,
listview is displaying correctly, but the check box is not displaying.
My code is like this:

```
<script id="script-id" type="text/x-kendo-template">

 <a href="\#next_view" class="km-listview-link" data-role="listview-link">
       <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
       <h3 class="time">#: firstname  #</h3>
       <h3>#: sentdate #</h3>
 </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Kendo UI does support binding and stylizing of the checkbox input:

```
<script id="script-id" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
        <h3 class="time">#: firstname  #</h3>
        <h3>#: sentdate #</h3>
    </label>
</script>
```

I can't promise you that the list item will behave or display the way you are expecting if you also include the `<a>`. You may need to bind to the click event handler on the `<ul>`:

```
<ul data-role="list-view" data-bind="click: navigateToNextView"/>
```

Comment: did u try to add a checkbox inside the above template and run it? the checkbox is not visible. not sure if its a bug in the current version.

Comment: I did try, and the checkbox did not appear when an `<a>` was also in the template. That is why I suggest removing the `<a>` (if possible) and using the click event handler on the `list-view`. Not ideal, but I thought I would give the question asker some options.

That being said, I have found myself moving away from using the input checkbox and `<a>` to navigate inside list-view templates because they don't seem to work acceptably on iOS device touch events.

Comment: for me even if the anchro tag is removed the checkbox dont appear.. pls check this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/obajih/9/ .

Comment: http://jsbin.com/obajih/11/edit Without digging into the default kendo mobile css, I believe the `<label>` tag is ciritical to the proper display of the checkbox style.

Comment: where r u testing the sample code? I still cant see the checkbox in chrome and safari on windows 7 machine

Comment: Chrome. Forgive me for asking, did you click on any of the list items? my example had them unchecked by default. Alternative: http://jsbin.com/obajih/12/edit

Comment: Cool.. Now i saw it... looks weird to have it wrapped inside a label. upvoting your answer.

Comment: hi! how to maintain the checked state when using filter on a listview?

Answer (score 0):

**answer edited using input from Gene C**
As Gene C pointed out if wrapped inside a  check box appears fine.

If you convert your checkbox to a switch view the code will work fine.  also you should not add data-role="listview-link" in your template. this will be automatically added by kendo when your template is attached to the list view. 
When we have clickable widgets inside your list item, we shud not add a hyperlink to wrap all the items. its better to have a button to do the navigation if u expect users to check the switch button and then navigate.

Here is a full working sample in jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/obajih/3/edit

ive changed your template to this:

```
<script id="script-id" type="text/x-kendo-template">

       <div>
       <input type="checkbox" data-role="switch" />
    </div>
       <h3 class="time">#: firstname  #</h3>
       <h3>#: sentdate #</h3>

    </script>

  </div>
```

Comment: hi! how to maintain the checked state when using filter on a listview?